# Undefined index: 'id' - php

Tags: php, mysqli

Quero recuperar os dados do mysql para editar, no entanto o 'id' não está sendo identificado. Consigo recuperar apenas o primeiro cadastro feito no msqli

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id_cliente'];  **-> Notice: Undefined index: id_cliente in C:\... **
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente";
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Erro ao executar a consulta." . mysqli_error($con));
$dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
?>

<body>
<form class="row g-3" method="post" name="form_cliente">
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="nome_cliente" class="form-label">NÚMERO DO CLIENTE</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_cliente" value="<?=$dados["id_cliente"]; ?>" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="nome_cliente" class="form-label">NOME COMPLETO</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_cliente" value="<?= $dados["nome_cliente"]; ?>" required>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você não está passando o id para a consulta SQL. Isso quando recebe um id (a mensagem de erro que você colocou diz que não está chegando o id_cliente no PHP, precisa tratar esse caso)

Comment: Nunca [duplique perguntas](/q/589352/70).- observe sempre as orientações da pergunta original, e se necessário edite-a para suprir informações faltantes quando for o caso. Para evitar descentralização de informações, o campo de comentarios foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na postagem original se restaurada.